# MySQL - filter from same column - return matched rows and - separate columns for filter

Tags: mysql

A table **`DATA_TABLE`** has 2 different numerical data, in the same column - **`Engine_Technical`**

The table has a separate column - **`Engine_Technical_Type`** - that Identifies 
the **type** of data **`Engine_Technical`** - that being **"CO2 EMISSIONS"** or **"MPG"**

The table also has a column - **`TECH_Id`** - that is not unique, and is specific to a vehicle.

I want to be able to make one query, that filters rows, that don't match the 2 separate input criteria values.

**For example:**

I would like to find vehicles that have a **MPG** less than **25** and **Emissions** = to lets say **17**

I am just not sure how to return rows with both, when the data I am filtering is in the same Column.

Two separate queries work

/* for MPG */

```
SELECT * FROM `DATA_TABLE` 

WHERE `TECH_Id` = 111

AND `Engine_Technical_Type` = "MPG"

AND `Engine_Technical` < 25
```

/* for CO2 */

```
SELECT * FROM `DATA_TABLE` 

WHERE `TECH_Id` = 111

AND `Engine_Technical_Type` = "CO2 EMISSIONS"

AND `Engine_Technical` = 17
```

---

```
|DATA_TABLE|
| TECH_Id | Engine_Technical_Type | Engine_Technical |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |        15        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |        17        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |         MPG           |        15        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |        15        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |         MPG           |        35        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  111    |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |        15        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  999   |          MPG           |        10        |
------------------------------------------------------
|  999    |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |        17        |
------------------------------------------------------
```

desired result:

```
|VEHICLE|
|ID|| TECH_Id |     CO2 EMISSIONS     |       MPG        |
----------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   111   |          17           |        15        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I just need to do this in one query and have the MPG and CO2 EMISSIONS in a separate column.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look into CASE WHEN syntax

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `case`:

```
select id, tech_id
     , sum(case engine_technical_type
           when 'CO2 EMISSIONS' then engine_technical
       end) as co2_emissions
     , sum(case engine_technical_type
           when 'MPG' then engine_technical
       end) as mpg
from data_table
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tech_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Engine_Technical_Type = 'MPG' THEN Engine_Technical END) as mpg,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Engine_Technical_Type = 'CO2 EMISSIONS' THEN Engine_Technical END) as co2_emissions
FROM `DATA_TABLE` 
WHERE `TECH_Id` = 111 AND
      ((Engine_Technical_Type = 'MPG' AND Engine_Technical < 25) OR
       (Engine_Technical_Type` = 'CO2 EMISSIONS' AND `Engine_Technical` = 17)
      )
GROUP BY tech_id;
```

I am not sure what `id` is supposed to be.